# Spyder 4.1.1: Error: "Completion & Linting in the editor for Python files will not work"

Tags: anaconda, spyder

Complete Error: **"Completion & Linting in the editor for Python files will not work during current session, or stopped working"**

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFa4N.png)
This error started appearing once I have upgraded to Spyder 4.1.1.

I have tried **Tools --> Preferences --> Completion and linting** 
Unchecked "Enable code completion" & "Enable code snippets"

However, the same error kept appearing every few seconds. Is there is any way to fix/ stop this. Any suggestion is appreciable!

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) It's not possible to hide that dialog and we decided to do that in order for people to be aware that code completion and linting is broken for them.

Instead, please start Spyder from the Anaconda Prompt or a terminal with the following command

`spyder --debug-info verbose --debug-output file`

let it run until the dialog appears and upload the file called `spyder-debug.log` (saved in the directory where you started Spyder) to our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues).

Answer (score 0):

I used "terminal" instead of file. File was crashing due to admin permissions.

spyder --debug-info verbose --debug-output terminal

After much digging i started to get an idea that kite that i initially installed and uninstalled still had some footprint and was getting in the way. It seems like it was working, but crossing streams.

So I deleted the following folders

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\spyder-4.1.5-py38_0\Lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\completion\kite

%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\pkgs\spyder-4.1.5-py38_0\Lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\completion\kite

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Kite

then i made sure I got rid of all options leading to Kite in spyder/tools/preferences/completion and linting

Linting and completion works seemlessly now. I liked kite, but the ram is was eating was ungodly and the licencing popups and work laptop .. i just didn't want to deal with it.